# how can i get the remote file /proc/loadavg

Tags: ubuntu, scp, cat

i have one vm  and one server (both of them are ubuntu)

i want to cat the /proc/loadavg data on the vm from the server

i have tried to use the command

> scp root@vm:/proc/loadavg .

but the file i scp is always empty (no size no content).

i ssh to the vm, use

> cat /proc/loadavg

, and the data is correct

how can i get correct data  the remote vm from my server?

thank you :)

Comment: Workaround: ssh root@vm 'cat /proc/loadavg'